# Best way to input a compiled AUTOIT program

Tags: autoit

Context:

I am going to write a AUTOIT script that will distribute to many people (let's call it `script.exe`). People using my program required to input `script.exe` only once and may run `script.exe` many times. Of course people can freely update the input as many times as they will.

So first I came up with approach that using the input file, then my program could read, parse then use it. Some improvement could be done is using `json` format. But this way is so complicated in my opinion so I came up with solution 2.

Solution 2 is my `script.exe` will import `input.au3` with content like:

```
$input1 = '...'
$input2 = '...'
$input3 = '...'
$input4 = '...'
```

Then I will compile `script.exe` and keep `input.au3` not compiled so that people can freely update the `input.au3`. This approach help me solve the problem so naturally but I end up don't know how to do that.

So my question:

1. How to compile a program but exclude some included file to be not compiled?
2. Is there any way better than my solution? Or even any existed library that help solution 1 so easy to approach?

Comment: Take a look at `IniRead()` and related commands. I think an `.INI` file is what you want.

Comment: `IniRead()` works brilliantly as want I want. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want (an external file that contains user-editable variables) is called an `.INI` file. Those files have historically a fixed format, structured in "Sections" and may look like:

```
[INPUTFILE]
; comment
Folder=C:\in
File=test.txt

[OUTPUTFILE]
Folder=C:\out
File=test.csv
Delimiter=;
```

AutoIt is able to work with those `.INI` files (read a key from a specific section, change it, or add one, or delete it).

For example you can read a specific key with:

```
$delim = Iniread(@ScriptDir & "\MyIni.ini", "OutputFile", "Delimiter", ",")
```

where `$delims` defaults to `,`, when the key was not found in the `.ini` file (last parameter)

`IniReadSection` reads a whole section into an array.

The advantage of an `INI` file is, it doesn't contain the actual variable names, but human-readable "keys"; their values are assigned to a variable with `IniRead`